# Adding user to group chrome-remote-desktop - Failed to access group. Is the user a member?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created an instance with Debian 9 and was following the instructions on Google's site [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine).  I have done this before successfully.  All was going fine, but now when I do this part:

```
DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host \
    --code="4/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \
    --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" \
    --name=
```

I get the error

> Adding user newuser_gmail_com to group chrome-remote-desktop
>   ERROR:Failed to access chrome-remote-desktop group. Is the user a
>   member?

Can anyone help me out here?   I notice that when I did this previously, the username create was not newuser_gmail_com, but rather simply newuser.  Any suggestions you have would be much appreciated.   Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, but this raises a possible bug for the Google Cloud team.  The bug occurs if I add enable-oslogin = TRUE as a metadata.   This causes the chrome-remote-desktop to fail.

Answer (score 0):

When a user is added to a group (`chrome-remote-desktop` in this case), the change is not reflected in existing sessions until the user logs out and back in. To work around this limitation, Chrome Remote Desktop attempts to use `sg` to access the new group from the existing session. It looks like this isn't working for some reason on this system (apparently OS Login related?), so starting the host fails.

It should be sufficient to log out and back in. Once logged back in, very that the output of `groups` contains `chrome-remote-desktop`, then try running the headless setup flow again. (Make sure you generate a new command, as the `--code` argument is one-time-use only.)